# Framework Similar to Pylons for Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, model-view-controller, frameworks, pylons

I've been using Python for most of my web projects lately, and have come to really love the Pylons MVC framework.  I like the incredible transparency (lack of magic), the built-in components they selected (sqlalchemy, formencode, routes), and the ability to easily change things up (use a different ORM or templating engine).

Moving forward, due to constraints at my company, I'm going to be trying out Ruby rather than Python.  I'm wondering if people with experience in both have any recommendations for a Ruby framework that is comparable to Pylons.

Python is to Django as Ruby is to Rails

Python is to Pylons as Ruby is to ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with pylons so its tough for me to compare, but if you are looking for a lightweight alternative to Rails, definitely check out [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). However, keep in mind its not an MVC framework.

[Ramaze](http://ramaze.net/) is another alternative which is ORM and templating engine agnostic.

Comment: merb has been [merged into rails](https://www.google.com/search?q=merb+merged+into+rails&oq=merb+merged+into+rail)

Comment: Updated answer to remove Merb.

Answer (score 0):

Python is to Django as Ruby is to Rails

Python is to Pylons as Ruby is to [Merb](http://merbivore.com/), is my best guess.

But since Merb and Rails are converging in the almost-released Rails 3.0 (at [Beta 3](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/4/13/rails-3-0-third-beta-release) right now) - the [lead developer](http://yehudakatz.com/) for Merb now performs the same role in the united product, I'd suggest that

Python is to Pylons as Ruby is to Rails 3.0

YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I am not sure how it compares to Pylons, but if you appreciate simplicity and transparency, you will definitely like Sinatra. And if you decide to give it a try, I would also recommend you [Monk](http://monkrb.com/) if you're already used to an MVC framework.